# Hex Color for Button Background - Kivy

Tags: android, python, button, widget, kivy

I'm struggling a bit here.

Is there a way to use `hex color` code for the `button_background` ?

I know about

```
canvas:
   Color:
     rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#ffffff")
```

But I want to use it for the Button

```
Button:
                text:'Solutions'
                background_normal: ''
                background_color: 1,1,1,1
                color:0,0,0,1
                halign:'center'
                on_release:
                    app.root.current='flamingowindow'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use hex values for colour

### kv file

- Add import statement for Kivy utility, `#:import rgba kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex`
- Replace `background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1` with `background_color: rgba("#ffffff")`

## Example

The following illustrates changing the button's background colour to #ffff60.

### main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder


runTouchApp(Builder.load_string("""
#:import rgba kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

Button:
    text:'Solutions'
    background_normal: ''
    # background_color: rgba("#ffffff")
    background_color: rgba("#ffff60")
    color:0,0,0,1
    halign:'center'
"""))
```

## Output

[image: Button's background_color changed]